# Restrict usage of the same password during a time period

Tags: password, pam

I need to configure a server with some requisites on the password changing: in addition to other requisites, I need to ensure that, on a password change, it is not repeated (last 5 passwords) and during 180 days.

The first part (5 last passwords) can be easy done using `pam_pwcheck remember=5` option, but I don't know how to ensure the 180-days requisite.

Any idea?

Comment: Here's an overview of the features offered by pam_cracklib: http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/pam_cracklib.html

Comment: Thanks @slm, but it is not enough. The `remember` option is very similar to `pam_pwcheck` one, and there is nothing about "not repeating the same password in the next X days" option. The maximum age for a password is another requisite, but it is solved with the default options passed to `useradd` or `passwd`. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Yeah I didn't think it was enough, I was putting it on your Q more as a reference for others in the future and you in case you hadn't seen these features documented anywhere else.

Comment: As I recall, the best I saw implemented with vanilla options was the history, but it was easy to overcome by simply chaning your password +6 times to loop it out of the history. I'll keep looking though.

Comment: @JoseLSegura I'm assuming that you're trying to avoid peple setting five (for example) random passwords then resetting it to what it was originally? Usually if you set a minimum password age (same places you're doing max) that's good enough. If you force them to use each password for at least a week then it becomes easier for the users to just keep using their new passwords.

Comment: I say that because there's really no mechanism for what you're trying to do (and I've looked high and low for it) and near as I can tell it's because minimum password age enforcement gets things close enough to the mark for most people.

Comment: First, thanks all for your comments. I really don't want to do that, but it is a requisite from another department, so I'm required to "do and shut up" :-D. The min and max age for a password are ok, but it doesn't fit the requisite. Again, thanks for your comments and advices!

Comment: I used  to work at a fortune 500 company that had instilled this type of policy. The best they could determine to implement this was to set the history to 10, but they weren't able to better than that either. So ppl would often put 11 passwords in to cycle back to their current password. Not until they used Active Directory and/or a 3rd party product with it's own PAM modules were they able to get what you are looking for. Not trying to deter your search, just giving you a data point 8-).